# text box not properly triggering multiple criteria lookup in userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a function in a userform I'm using to lookup a row within a worksheet to extract 3 cell values once the proper row has been matched. I figure I needed to place the sub within the last value that's triggered.

```
Private Sub txtCompCode_Change()
    Dim recRow As Range
    Set recRow = MatchSalaryRange(Worksheets("Salary Ranges").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                          Me.cmbPosition.Value, _
                          txtCompCode.Text)
    If recRow Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With recRow.EntireRow
        .Cells(4).Value = Me.txtMIN.Text
        .Cells(5).Value = Me.txtMID.Text
        .Cells(6).Value = Me.txtMAX.Text
    End With
End Sub
Function MatchSalaryRange(tablerange As Range, lPosition, lCompCode) As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    For Each rw In tablerange.Rows
        If CStr(rw.Cells(2).Value) = CStr(lPosition) Then
            If rw.Cells(3).Value = lCompCode Then
                Set MatchSalaryRange = rw
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
End Function
```

it first references a job title in a text box and then a compensation code in another text box. then it locates the row, supposed to pull columns D:E in order to populate the Min/Mid/Max text boxes, but it's not doing so.

Any ideas?

EDIT: based on this  after the right text box in yellow is selected, it should trigger the function for the red text boxes below.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint does it ever hit the inner `If` in your function?

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly is happening. What do the cells contain (cell 1 / 2), what does `cmbPosition` contain, what does `txtCompCode` contain. As @TimWilliams suggested, doing some debugging should tell you more.

Comment: @NidenK It seems that this is caused by the event type of `txtCompCode`. The `Change` event triggers as soon as the value of the textbox changes, perhaps one of the other events is better used, `AfterUpdate` for example (though I need to know more about the use case). Is store number another textbox which automatically fills the `txtCompCode` textbox?

Comment: @TimWilliams ok so I changed the event type to the job position selection in order to trigger the sub. It never reaches the inner IF, what could be causing that?

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry, it's now hitting the `set matchsalaryrange = rw` part, but it's saying it's set to nothing

Comment: That part looks fine to me...

Comment: if it gets to that point then rw should have a value, what if the debug hits Exit function and you hover over rw, is it nothing?

Comment: @Nicolas once debug hits exit, its showing rw is nothing in the locals window. I can't hover over it and have it display a value, it doesnt show anything.

Comment: That's weird since the rw.Cells conditions are met, so rw has a value for sure. Though my Excel VBA it a bit rusty, do you have a repo of your workbook or can you create one so I could look a bit better what is going on.

Comment: @TimWilliams so i stepped through to where it sets the matched row and looked in the locals window, it says row 34 in my data, which is the correct row. What could be causing the set = nothing?

Comment: @Nicolas what's your email, I have a dummy data workbook I can send you

Comment: @NidenK use https://www.filedropper.com/ or something similar

Comment: There's nothing in your code which would explain the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: @Nicolas https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AAC-XTSJBUKfZwi9y4g7c0Teoz1WPajV3PY

Comment: @Nicolas gave you access to the file, sorry about the wait

Comment: @TimWilliams So I set a watch in multiple areas: the rw.address is correct, but when I set a watch on the `rw.cells(...).value = ` is showing the values as the headers for those columns. Do I need to change up those if statement lines?

Comment: Do you have blank rows in your data?  Would be easier looking at your workbook - no need to restrict access unless it has sensitive information...

Comment: @TimWilliams sent you the workbook

Comment: Working fine for me...

Comment: @TimWilliams the salary range text boxes aren't filling in the values from the matched worksheet though.

Comment: @TimWilliams refer to my picture in my post, the red text boxes aren't populating anything

Comment: Your code moves values from the textboxes to the sheet, not from the sheet to the textboxes...  That part works fine for me (though I was confused as to why you'd do that...)

Comment: wow, ok that solved it

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to switch around this block:

```
    With recRow.EntireRow
        Me.txtMIN.Text = .Cells(4).Value
        Me.txtMID.Text = .Cells(5).Value
        Me.txtMAX.Text = .Cells(6).Value
    End With
```